# What is the difference between 'Variable' and 'Variable/Momentum' in Tensorflow checkin file?

Tags: tensorflow

I use 'print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file' to get the following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr4kI.png), but should I choose to use  'Variable'  or 'Variable/Momentum'? Thanks.